# Looking for a list of items in a query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am passing a string list of studentKeys to my LINQ to Entities query.
So I want to return those data that are in that coming list.

```
public IQueryable<Students> GetStudentsFromKeys(List<string> studentKeys)
{
    var result = from a in this.Context.Students
    where // ?

    return result.ToList();
}
```

But How should I actually write such a query? I want to query that table and if its keys are the same as one of the keys in that list, return it as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
var result = from a in this.Context.Students
             where studentKeys.Contains(a.StudentKey)
             select a;
```

Or with method syntax as:

```
var query = this.Context.Students
                        .Where(r => studentKeys.Contains(r.StudentKey));
```

*(assuming `StudentKey` is the name of the field you want to compare)*

This would generate query similar to

```
SELECT * from Students WHERE StudentKey in ("1","2","3")
```

Comment: it would be better to do a case insensitive contains.

Comment: @Chaitanya, not really sure if it is required or not

Comment: @Habib It is just that it is more safe and correct. Something like, 

var query = this.Context.Students.Where(r => studentKeys.Contains(r.StudentKey, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

Comment: @Chaitanya By default, it will use the collation of the column in the table. Doing a `StringComparer.OrginalIgnoreCase` does not map to a SQL statement and will either not work (with a NotSupportedException) or do the comparison in-memory by pulling all the record before the predicate and filtering then.

Comment: @Chaitanya, I am not sure if that would translate into under laying data source language *(SQL may be)*, Also It is not specified by the OP so I would rather stay away from it :)

Comment: @SimonBelanger I did not anticipate that it might pull the records and then filter. thank you for clarifying.